# How do I add a toggle button to switch the player in and out of first person in roblox when 'f' is pressed. in roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

I want to make it so that when F is pressed it puts the player into first person and when it is pressed a second time it puts them back into 3rd. Thanks for your time.

I have tried many things this being one of them
all that needs fixing is returning the camera back to zoomed out when in 3rd person

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local userInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")

local function toggleCameraMode()
    if player.CameraMode == Enum.CameraMode.LockFirstPerson then
        player.CameraMode = Enum.CameraMode.Classic
        player.CameraDistance = 5
        if player.Character then
            player.CameraSubject = player.Character.Humanoid
        end
        player.CameraDistance = 5 -- Adjust the desired camera distance
    else
        player.CameraMode = Enum.CameraMode.LockFirstPerson
    end
end

-- Function to handle key presses
local function onKeyPress(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.F then
        toggleCameraMode()
    end
end

-- Bind the onKeyPress function to the KeyPressed event
userInputService.InputBegan:Connect(onKeyPress)
```